# Image selected in html/js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a rating system, ten images of numbers, (1, 2, 3... and so on), and I'd like to know how could I put to those images a value, (1, 2, 3... respectively), inside of a form, so when user click on submit, I can get in PHP the value from the pic selected.

Basically I don't know how to make it know which image is being selected in.

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 order-md-1 offset-md-3">
      <h4 class="mb-3">Rate system</h4>
      <form class="needs-validation" method="POST" action="test.php">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gustavo" name="name" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Is a name is necessary.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-1" src="1.png">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-1" src="2.png">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-1" src="3.png">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-1" src="4.png">
            <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-1" src="5.png">
          </div>

        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">¡Go!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: @Grumpy done, every picture would be like a button you can select it, but not sure how could I know what picture the user clicked in once he pressed the submit button.

Comment: @Sharki assuming you have an hidden input with multiple file . Then you click select images and use jquery to append those images to a div as previewing, each image have an unique `id` and `data-selected = "0 | 1"` 0 = not select | 1 = selected. Then you check data-selected of what equal to 1 and add that file to `FormData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **value** for star after clicking on **star symbol** & change as well as **data-star** attribute value for selected stars. After selected stars will highlighted as play with some CSS code with help of **:nth-child(number)** function.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.list-star li', function(){
  $(this).parent().attr('data-star', Number($(this).index())+1);
  $('#setRating').val(Number($(this).index())+1);
});
```

```css
.list-star li{
  color: #999;
  margin-right: 0px!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
[data-star="1"] li:nth-child(1),
[data-star="2"] li:nth-child(1), [data-star="2"] li:nth-child(2),
[data-star="3"] li:nth-child(1), [data-star="3"] li:nth-child(2), [data-star="3"] li:nth-child(3),
[data-star="4"] li:nth-child(1), [data-star="4"] li:nth-child(2), [data-star="4"] li:nth-child(3), [data-star="4"] li:nth-child(4),
[data-star="5"] li {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10">
      <h4 class="mb-3">Rate system</h4>
      <form class="needs-validation" method="POST" action="test.php">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gustavo" name="name" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Is a name is necessary.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <ul class="list-inline list-star" data-star="0">
              <li class="list-inline-item">&#9733;</li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">&#9733;</li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">&#9733;</li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">&#9733;</li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">&#9733;</li>
            </ul>
            <input type="number" name="rating" placeholder="Rating Value" id="setRating" readonly>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Go!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input>` tag and set its `value` either by js or php. Give each img an `id` and add `onclick` listener that changes the input value, which will collect the `form` at the end ;)